# route resource update and delete not working using multiple roles except store laravel 8

Tags: laravel, laravel-8, laravel-routing, laravel-middleware, laravel-authentication

I want to `delete` my admin product using a route resource. But when I submit, it goes to page `404` same as `update` method.. But my URL `id` is showing...

This is the URL on `destroy` method `http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/1`  but the store is working fine. It's directing to my URL and `stored` in database.

This is my `store` method on `Admin/ProductController` resource:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $request['user_id'] = auth()->user()->id;
    Product::create($request->all());

    return redirect()->back();
}
```

This is my `destroy` method on `Admin/ProductController` resource:

```
 public function destroy($id)
 {
     Product::where('id', $id->id)->delete();

     return redirect()->back();
 }
```

Here is my form action `store` method. This form is working fine:

```
<form method="post" action="{{route('admin.store')}}">
    <input type="text" name="category" class="form-control">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
</form>
```

Here is my form action `delete`. The problem is when I submit, it goes to `404` page:

```
<form method="post" action="{{ route('admin.destroy', $product->id) }}">
    <input type="text" name="category" class="form-control">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
</form>
```

Here is my route `user` and `admin`:

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});

Auth::routes();

Route::group(['as' => 'user.', 'prefix' => 'users', 'namespace' => 'App\Http\Controllers\Users'], function() {
    Route::get('/', [App\Http\Controllers\Users\UsersController::class, 'index']);
    Route::resources(['/' => ProductController::class], ['except' => ['index']]);
});

Route::group(['middleware' => 'admin', 'as' => 'admin.', 'prefix' => 'admin', 'namespace' => 'App\Http\Controllers\Admin'], function() {
    Route::get('/', [App\Http\Controllers\Admin\AdminController::class, 'index']);
    Route::resources(['/' => ProductController::class], ['except' => ['index']]);
});
```

Here is my route list:

```
+--------+-----------+------------------------+------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------+------------+
| Domain | Method    | URI                    | Name             | Action                                                                 | Middleware |
+--------+-----------+------------------------+------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------+------------+
|        | GET|HEAD  | /                      |                  | Closure                                                                | web        |
|        | POST      | admin                  | admin.store      | App\Http\Controllers\Admin\ProductController@store                     | web        |
|        |           |                        |                  |                                                                        | admin      |
|        | GET|HEAD  | admin                  | admin.index      | App\Http\Controllers\Admin\ProductController@index                     | web        |
|        |           |                        |                  |                                                                        | admin      |
|        | GET|HEAD  | admin/create           | admin.create     | App\Http\Controllers\Admin\ProductController@create                    | web        |
|        |           |                        |                  |                                                                        | admin      |
|        | DELETE    | admin/{}               | admin.destroy    | App\Http\Controllers\Admin\ProductController@destroy                   | web        |
|        |           |                        |                  |                                                                        | admin      |
|        | PUT|PATCH | admin/{}               | admin.update     | App\Http\Controllers\Admin\ProductController@update                    | web        |
|        |           |                        |                  |                                                                        | admin      |
|        | GET|HEAD  | admin/{}               | admin.show       | App\Http\Controllers\Admin\ProductController@show                      | web        |
|        |           |                        |                  |                                                                        | admin      |
|        | GET|HEAD  | admin/{}/edit          | admin.edit       | App\Http\Controllers\Admin\ProductController@edit                      | web        |
|        |           |                        |                  |                                                                        | admin      |
|        | GET|HEAD  | api/user               |                  | Closure                                                                | api        |
|        |           |                        |                  |                                                                        | auth:api   |
|        | POST      | login                  |                  | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\LoginController@login                        | web        |
|        |           |                        |                  |                                                                        | guest      |
|        | GET|HEAD  | login                  | login            | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\LoginController@showLoginForm                | web        |
|        |           |                        |                  |                                                                        | guest      |
|        | POST      | logout                 | logout           | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\LoginController@logout                       | web        |
|        | GET|HEAD  | password/confirm       | password.confirm | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\ConfirmPasswordController@showConfirmForm    | web        |
|        |           |                        |                  |                                                                        | auth       |
|        | POST      | password/confirm       |                  | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\ConfirmPasswordController@confirm            | web        |
|        |           |                        |                  |                                                                        | auth       |
|        | POST      | password/email         | password.email   | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\ForgotPasswordController@sendResetLinkEmail  | web        |
|        | GET|HEAD  | password/reset         | password.request | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\ForgotPasswordController@showLinkRequestForm | web        |
|        | POST      | password/reset         | password.update  | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\ResetPasswordController@reset                | web        |
|        | GET|HEAD  | password/reset/{token} | password.reset   | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\ResetPasswordController@showResetForm        | web        |
|        | GET|HEAD  | register               | register         | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\RegisterController@showRegistrationForm      | web        |
|        |           |                        |                  |                                                                        | guest      |
|        | POST      | register               |                  | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\RegisterController@register                  | web        |
|        |           |                        |                  |                                                                        | guest      |
|        | GET|HEAD  | users                  | user.            | App\Http\Controllers\Users\UsersController@index                       | web        |
|        | POST      | users                  | user.store       | App\Http\Controllers\Users\ProductController@store                     | web        |
|        |           |                        |                  |                                                                        | auth       |
|        | GET|HEAD  | users/create           | user.create      | App\Http\Controllers\Users\ProductController@create                    | web        |
|        |           |                        |                  |                                                                        | auth       |
|        | DELETE    | users/{}               | user.destroy     | App\Http\Controllers\Users\ProductController@destroy                   | web        |
|        |           |                        |                  |                                                                        | auth       |
|        | GET|HEAD  | users/{}               | user.show        | App\Http\Controllers\Users\ProductController@show                      | web        |
|        |           |                        |                  |                                                                        | auth       |
|        | PUT|PATCH | users/{}               | user.update      | App\Http\Controllers\Users\ProductController@update                    | web        |
|        |           |                        |                  |                                                                        | auth       |
|        | GET|HEAD  | users/{}/edit          | user.edit        | App\Http\Controllers\Users\ProductController@edit                      | web        |
|        |           |                        |                  |                                                                        | auth       |
+--------+-----------+------------------------+------------------+---------------------------------------
```

Here is my `App\Http\Auth\LoginController`:

```php
namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class LoginController extends Controller
{
    use AuthenticatesUsers;

    protected $redirectTo = RouteServiceProvider::HOME;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest')->except('logout');
    }

    public function login(Request $request)
    {
        $inputVal = $request->all();

        $this->validate($request, [
            'email' => 'required|email',
            'password' => 'required',
        ]);

        if (auth()->attempt(['email' => $inputVal['email'], 'password' => $inputVal['password']])) {
            if (auth()->user()->role == 'admin') {
                return redirect()->route('admin.');
            } else {
                return redirect()->route('user');
            }
        } else {
            return redirect()->route('login')
                ->with('error', 'Email & Password are incorrect.');
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my `admin middleware`:

```
namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class Admin
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next)
    {
        if (auth()->user()->role === 'admin') {
            return $next($request);
        }

        return redirect()->back();
    }
}
```

I don't know what is wrong on this, `store` is working but the `update` and `destroy` is not. I guess the error is on `route` or `middleware`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your problem is that your are not telling your `delete` form to use `DELETE` action. Because of HTML, you cannot use `action="delete"` so you have to *fake it* and Blade allows you to do that.

So try this:

```html
<form method="post" action="{{ route('admin.destroy', $product->id) }}">
    @csrf
    @method('DELETE')
    <input type="text" name="category" class="form-control">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
</form>
```

More info about it on the [Blade documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/blade#method-field).

---

Same fix should be applied in your `update`, you should use `@method('PUT')` after your update form's tag.

Comment: hello thank you for your answered. i tried your sample but its still same goes to 404

Comment: I think there is something wrong with your routes, see one route has `{token}` but your `admin` and `user` has `{}`, like it is missing the `param`. Like [this example](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/controllers#actions-handled-by-resource-controller)

Comment: but when im not using resource and i use this 
Route::delete('/',[App\Http\Controllers\Admin\AdminController::class,'destroy'])->name('destroy');
its working fine

Comment: You have to use my `blade` fix (`method`) and still fix your routes.

Comment: But you are declaring a `resource`, when you do `Route::delete` it works, because you are already saying "go to route / with delete" but using a resource, you need a parameter, that is why you see `admin/{}` and not `admin/`

Comment: same as update
 Route::update('/',[App\Http\Controllers\Admin\AdminController::class,'update'])->name('update');

Comment: it doesn't matter, check your routes with that `AdminController` and see if you have something like `admin/{}` or what you have ? If you go to `admin/123/edit` will it work with a correct id ? or it does still show 404 ?

Comment: yeah but my resource parameter admin/{} its not working it showing like on my form delete action when i tried to submit it goes to error 404 page.. but the parameter admin/1 is there

Comment: okay i will check it AdminController thank you for your effort

Comment: @RayParas, is it working `Route::update('/',[App\Http\Controllers\Admin\AdminController::class,'update'])->name('update');`?

Comment: it still does show 404, when im using resource i checked my route:list update has admin/{}
but when im trying to single like 
Route::patch('/',[App\Http\Controllers\Admin\AdminController::class,'update'])->name('update')
it show on route admin only on URI without a bracket 
and even i put a http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/5 on the URI it still 404

Comment: yes its working when i do that but when resource is not working

Comment: ``Route::group(['middleware'=>'admin','as'=>'admin.','prefix'=>'admin','namespace'=>'App\Http\Controllers\Admin'],
    function (){
        Route::get('/',[App\Http\Controllers\Admin\AdminController::class,'index']);
        Route::post('/',[App\Http\Controllers\Admin\ProductController::class,'store'])->name('store');
        Route::patch('/',[App\Http\Controllers\Admin\ProductController::class,'update'])->name('update');
    });``

this working fine without resource but i guess its bad to do this

Comment: @RayParas, I usually use individual `route` not resource and it works fine for me at all. I have not faced this type of problem till now

Comment: its okay man. thank you for your help. until now i still not solve this problem with resource controller. and im new at laravel 8 im trying to create a multi users. but what im trying to do is i guess its a wrong to create a multi users with these code i created.

Comment: man. can you give me a good sample creating a multi users role like this? if its okay to you

Comment: @RayParas send me your email please

Comment: okay thank you my friend. here is my email **luckyampzz@gmail.com**

Answer (score 1):

If your method is post then you have to also add `CSRF`

```html
<form method="post" action="{{ route('admin.destroy', $product->id) }}">
    {{ csrf_field() }}
    {{ method_field('delete') }}
    <input type="text" name="category" class="form-control">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
</form>
```